# Facebook registration plugin - remove undo popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, user-registration

In a rails application, I implemented facebook registration plugin

However, After clicking the "Register" button, the user is getting an undo dialog. I've observed several sites that also use the Registration plugin and do not display this dialog.

Please suggest me ways to remove this dialog?